# Finding the trapped area in matlab

Tags: matlab

%%I am trying to find the area trapped between two circles and a curve in Matlab, circle one: 10^2= x^2 + y^2 . circle two: 5^2= x^2 + y^2 . curve: y= x^2 . xaxis= [ -10 -5 0 5 10], yaxis [ -10 -5 0 5 10], x and y centre is  0. how can I find the area trapped between the three shapes?

Comment: You can either do this analytically (by far the cleanest) or find the intersections between the formula and then find out between what intersections your three-way overlap exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged matlab I assume you are not going for the cleanest solution (analytic, as suggested by @Adriaan). Finding the intersections would also require some analytical work, so I will suggest a method avoiding even that.

Plot the three lines and choose which of the trapped areas you want to find the area of (there are 2 or 4 depending on the definition).
Using [Monte Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) you can "throw darts" at your plot.
Use logical statements to see if the dart hits inside or outside the section.
The area is then the percentage of darts inside the section times the area of the section the darts are thrown at.
The more darts you throw the more exact the result will be.

Again, if you just want the exact result do it analytically. For help with that this is not the correct forum.